# Expecting a Matrix, function returns a scalar

Tags: matlab

I have a function that is supposed to return a matrix but it gives me a scalar. Here it is:

```
 function [lat,lon,h]=xyz2ell(X,Y,Z,a,e2)
 .....
```

in the script that calls the above function, i have assigned the return value to a variable like this (this might be where the problem is?):

```
 ellipsoid_geographisch_coord = xyz2ell(X,Y,Z,a,e2);
```

I'm a novice at Matlab, can someone pls point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this to call the function:

```
[lat,lon,h] = xyz2ell(X,Y,Z,a,e2);
```

Then the variable to which you assign a matrix in the function will have a matrix after the call